# Which point is taken as origin for sound wave equations?

Tags: acoustics

In sound wave problems mostly it is mentioned like there are two waves travelling in opposite directions like say $\sin (t-x)$ and $\sin (t+x)$ which produce stationary waves in a closed organ pipe (say).

In such a case which point is taken as origin for the equations  $\sin (t-x)$ and $\sin (t+x)$ ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean "which point is taken as origin"? If you have both $\sin(t-x)$ and $\sin(t+x)$, does it even *matter* in which direction the coordinate system lies? Doesn't the text you're using *say* what the coordinate system is? Please provide more details.

Comment: Oh that was my doubt actually..."can the coordinate system be in any random direction?" Thanks..you already answered in your comment but can you tell why ? @ACuriousMind

Comment: Well, again, without more context it is impossible to tell for sure, but isn't it obvious that one would naturally choose the coordinate system in which $x$ is *along the length of the pipe*?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is one simple thing you should do and that's doing that in right units:

$$
p = A\sin (\omega t - kx) + B\sin(\omega t + kx)
$$

Wthout $k$ and $\omega$ you can't add/subtract $x\pm t$.

As CuriousMind has commented, it doesn't matter which direction the coordinates axes takes. For these kind of applications there is better suited solution:

$$
p(x,t) = X(x)T(t) = (A'\cos kx + B'\sin kx)e^{i\omega t}
$$

and just play with the boundary conditions to obtain right $k$'s.